# Freez "x%" of a webpage vertically?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a way to freeze "x%" of a webpage vertically? I have a header & a div that follows the header that I'd like to freeze. In general, I would like to know if I can freeze "x%"

I did read about "position:fixed" styling. Am curious to know if there is way outside of that.

Comment: There's `position: sticky` too with limited browser support but that's about it. Unless you want to use a bunch of JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use fixed position on the header div:

```
#header {
    position: fixed; 
    top: 0px;
}
```

That will cause the header not to scroll, but always staying at the top of the browser area. Read more on [W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp).

This, however, freezes a certain element and not a specific percentage of the page. To my knowledge that is not possible to accomplish, since the percentage limit might cut through elements. What would happend to those?

Comment: Thank you Anders. I used this . Honestly, I didn't think about the elements being cut through. Thank you for the guidance there.